Customizer copyright in Footer Bar
I am running a WordPress (latest version 6.5) staging website in WAMP64 in fact, I am running two versions of this website. There is a problem with the copyright text under the Footer Bar in Customizer. It is completely blank, I cannot do anything with it. I can’t type anything there and I can’t remove Powered by using CSS as I would normally do.
Here is the image:

This problem does not happen on the live website - only in WAMP. I tried to make sure that HTTPS is turned off in wp-config.php:
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/example.com');

This seems to work in one of my staging sites, but not this one. Can anybody advise me on this please? If this is not the right forum for posting this, perhaps you could advise me where I should be asking this question. Many thanks.

that UI is not a part of WordPress core, is it being added by your theme or code that you've added? Have you looked at the browsers dev tools error console for Javascript errors? Without a JS error or code to look at that implements the footer UI you took a screenshot of it'll be very difficult if possible to answer this

Thank you so much for responding. This seems to have been added by my theme - I have not added a code. I  up another Wordpress site with the same theme with no plugins and the same problem is there. I also looked at the browser development tools and the code seems to be alright there. I can't find a JavaScript there. I am not sure where I could look for something that would point to this anomaly.

As I mentioned, your server error logs are a huge clue, check where WAMP64 stores the PHP error logs, the browsers dev tools will only tell you about things that happen in the browser, they tell you almost nothing about what happens on the server/PHP. Without error messages or code there's almost nothing that can be done to help you. If this is an issue with a theme you bought though then you need to contact their support as you're not allowed ot ask for help with 3rd party products/themes/plugins here as that's outside the stacks scope

Thanks so much for your patience. I have finally nailed down this problem: I was viewing this in Firefox, but when I viewed it in Chrome or Opera there was not issue - it worked fine. I never thought that it would have something to do with that - it never happened before. That is why I forgot all about this possibility. Many thanks again.
